# JtextArea update issue not updating real time

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a application, which on a mouse click runs several methods which updates a JtextArea. The problem is even though I'm updating the text area with each method call, it doesn't actually update until everything in the mouseclick has run..

This can take quite a while to run through everything and I would like to see the text area update with each call instead of waiting until everything is done

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();

                dataCollected.append("Begining Test...\n\n");
                dataCollected.append("Collecting System Information... \n\n");
                dataCollected.append(dc.getSystem());
                                ... lots more like this...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't actually update until everything in the mouseclick has run.

That's totally correct. Your `mouseClicked` method is called on the GUI thread and this thread is the only thread which updates the GUI. So your "update textarea content" action is executed **after** your `mouseClicked` method finishes. Therefore your methods which run on the GUI thread should run extremely quick so other methods which wants to run on the GUI thread can do so.

You can start a new thread which runs in parallel to your normal code which will update your JTextArea. Read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) on how to work with threads in swing (and what the "Event Dispatch Thread" is).